# HABTM Form not submitting more than one value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, form-for

I am trying to assign a group of players to a fixture though a form.

I have been trying to list all the players from my *players* table via checkboxes so the user can select which players he wants for the fixture.

**Models**
There are 3 models concedered with the fixtures and players

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :team
has_many :player_fixtures
has_many :players, :through => :player_fixtures
has_one :venue

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
has_many :player_fixtures
has_many :fixtures, :through => :player_fixtures

class PlayerFixture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :fixture
```

I need to use a `:through` as with the association of the players and fixtures. I need a boolean whether that person has paid.

The associations of these work, and I can assign a player to a fixture in the join table though the console.

**Views**
In my view I have:

```
 <%= form_for(:fixture, :url => {:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

This is the code I have been trying to get to work at the moment!

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:player, :player_id, @players,:id, :name, { :include_blank => true ,:multiple => true}) %>
```

**EDIT**

I have now inserted the comment below and also changed the collection select to:

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all,:id, :name, {:include_blank => true ,:multiple => true}) %>
```

At the moment I get the following error on trying to load the form:

```
undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol
```

on this line

```
 28:       <td><%= f.collection_select(:fixture, :player_id, Player.all,:id, :name, { :include_blank => true ,:multiple => true}) %>
```

This is probably horribly wrong, however I really need to get this working as this is a large part of my project.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? If someone wants to send along the formtastic route, feel free, as I can not get that work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass object to the form_for instead of symbol:

```
<%=form_for(:fixture, :url => {:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for(@fixture, :url => {:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

**Update:**

Look like you did not define has_many :player_fixtures in the Fixture model, has_many :through required it first.

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :team
has_many :player_fixtures
has_many :players, :through => :player_fixtures
has_one :venue
```

Comment: I have done this however I still get some errors! *see the edit*

Comment: Done this however there is still another error annoyingly! Thanks for your help