# Has Many: though relationship problems. Submitting forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to have a many to many relationship between players and fixtures. So when a player has played in a fixture I can see what fixtures the players have played in and who has played in the fixtures.

I am trying to then track if the player has paid for the game using a "sub_paid" column with  boolean. I am having a hard time setting this to true or false. I can create a player/fixture record but not have a sub_paid attribute.

### Models

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :player_fixtures
has_many :players, :through => :player_fixtures

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :player_fixtures
has_many :fixtures, :through => :player_fixtures

class PlayerFixture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :fixture
```

### Migrations

```
class CreatePlayerFixtures < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :player_fixtures do |t|
   t.integer  "player_id"
   t.integer  "fixture_id"
   t.boolean  "sub_paid"

   t.timestamps
end
```

### Controller

Not sure what to put here as I have none specificity one for player_fixture

### View

I have this at the moment.

```
<%=form_for(@fixtures, :url => {:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

### questions

Could someone point me in the right direction!

My big questions that I am really stuck on at the moment.

1. Saving this to the database with sub_paid = false when form is first submitted then being able to change this at a later date to true.
2. Being able to sort all players by sub_paid = false on a fixture view. EG on my player list sort them so it only shows false.
3. I have another question here that is still un answered about forms and checkboxes. [HABTM Form not submitting more than one value in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897126/habtm-form-not-submitting-more-than-one-value-in-rails/9900192#9900192)

I understand this is alot but this is for a project I am doing and have been looking at a screen trying everything for 3 weeks now. I need to get this done.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the form view code? At least the part that's supposed to send the `sub_paid` attribute. It would help to see the parameters you're sending.

Comment: Oh, and the controller code for `FixturesController#create`.

Comment: I have form objects for other fields in the view for venue, date ect.... however none for sub_paid as I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your form:

```
<%= check_box_tag :sub_paid %>
<%= select_tag :player_id, options_for_select(Player.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id] %>
```

Note that these are ordinary `check_box_tag` and `select_tag` and not `f.check_box` or `f.select`. We don't want these parameters to be in your `:fixture` parameter. Now the `create` action in your `FixtureController` should look something like this:

```
def create
  @fixture = Fixture.new(params[:fixture])
  if @fixture.save
    @player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
    @fixture.player_fixtures << PlayerFixture.new(:sub_paid => params[:sub_paid], :player => @player)
    # other stuff, redirect, etc.
  else
    # error handling, render, etc.
  end
end
```

You should probably do some checks to make sure the `PlayerFixture` saving part goes well, but you get the idea. Hope that helps or at least gives you some ideas.

Comment: If I used your code I get nothing in the drop down box. Is there no way for the player_id selected from Players<%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt => true) %> to be used in the Controller?

Comment: Yes, except I'm not sure how you'll figure out which players are `sub_paid` and which aren't. If you can do that, just get the `ids` from the `params[:fixture][:player_ids]` parameter. If you can't, one other approach would be to list the players in the form, each which two checkboxes or radio buttons, one for `sub_paid == true` and one for `sub_paid == false`.